# How to force ADS to use a specific index in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

For example, I know how to do this in SQL Server. I can write something like the following:
`SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH(INDEX(MyIndex))`

I didn't find anything similar for Advantage Database Server..